# import data from text/csv file into sqlite table using python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I am working on a python application in which I connect to the existing SQLite database and table. I have a CSV file containing one value per row (stocks symbol) and I want to import all the values into the existing table column "symbol" using python.
How can I do this?

What I've tried is defining an insert function:

```
def insert(symbol):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("stocks.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO stocks (symbol) VALUES (?)", (symbol,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and then try looping in the value and adding the values from there:

```
with open("./stocks/sp500_tickers.csv") as data:
      tickers = data.read()
      for ticker in tickers:
          insert(ticker)
```

But when I run the python code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch.py", line 64, in <module>
    insert(ticker)
  File "fetch.py", line 23, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO stocks (symbol) VALUES (?)", (symbol,))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: stocks.symbol
```

The same thing happens if I try like this:

```
with open("./stocks/sp500_tickers.csv") as data:
      tickers = data.read()
      rows = tickers.split('\n')
      formatted = [tuple(x.split()) for x in rows]
      for ticker in tickers:
          insert(ticker)
```

The schema for the table is:

```
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        symbol VARCHAR, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        price NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        book_value NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        trailing_pe NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        forward_pe NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        trailing_eps NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        forward_eps NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        dividend_yield NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        ma50 NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        ma200 NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        sector VARCHAR, 
        growth_rate NUMERIC(10, 2), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX ix_stocks_id ON stocks (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_stocks_symbol ON stocks (symbol);
```

My "sp500_tickers.csv" looks something like this:

```
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ABMD
etc
```

Any help is very welcomed!

Comment: If `insert` fails, use `update`. For that you will have to perform individual transactions not a batch ttransaction.

Comment: Plus, never underestimate the power of the `print()` command to debug stuff like this i.e. `print("inserting", symbol)` . It pays to know what you are asking the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: stocks.symbol
```

it seems like the values you are trying to insert into the symbol column are not unique.
There is an unique index defined for that column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_stocks_symbol ON stocks (symbol);
```

You should either make sure the values you are inserting are unique or drop the unique index.

Comment: thank you for the comment, however I think there is something else wrong, I've made sure I don't have anything into the table and only tried with 2 values in the csv file and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This `tickers = data.read()` makes `tickers` one big string. This `for ticker in tickers:` iterates over each *character* in the string. Second attempt would fix that problem, if not for the typo here `for ticker in tickers:`

Once the input is converted to a list, there is actually no reason to iterate over it; that sort of defeats the purpose of `executemany` :)